# iOS app crashes with no crash details on version iOS 10.0 when present ViewController for the second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios10

An application runs for the first time after installation, the app is not get crashed when the memory usage goes up to 250+ MB where we present and pop the view controller, but once after we terminate the app and relaunch the application then present and pop view controller, it get crashed when memory usage reaches 80+ MB particularly in iOS 10.0

I have been working on fixing this for the past one week and I haven't find the reason for this crash yet. Application is based on presenting the pdf file. Application working fine on version 8.0 and 9.0 with this memory usage changes.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should write at least some code where you believe there is an error, also what does the debugger says? Can you enable an exception breakpoint?

Comment: The debugger says nothing,it simply get crashed and I don't know exactly where the crash happened whenever we present the any viewcontroller with memory usage of 80+ MB for the second time run,it crash. But it particularly in iOS 10.

Comment: I made a sample project to present viewcontroller in different manner (i.e Pushviewcontroller,modal present with popover, present with form sheet.) with memory usage 20+ MB, but it is working fine in it.